# adding a timeout delay to javascript?

Tags: javascript

can someone help me please i am trying to make this javascript start its function after a 3 second delay using time out.

I am still learning javascript and jquery and would be grateful if someone could show me where im going wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
window.onload = function showPopUp(el) {
var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
cvr.style.display = "block"
dlg.style.display = "block"
if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
    cvr.style.width = "1024"
    cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
    }
}
},3000);

</script>
```

Comment: You should really click here: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 2):

So in short, you have this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.onload = function() {
        // do stuff...
    }
}, 3000);
```

That's not going to work.  This says, after 3 seconds, assign a handler for the window's `onload` event.  At that point the event already (most likely) fired.  So this funciton won't execute.

Instead, flip it around.

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // do stuff...
    }, 3000);
}
```

So here, when the window loads, you do something 3 seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.onload = function showPopUp(el) {
```

This assigns an `onload` handler after 3 seconds, by which time the window has likely already loaded.

---

Get rid of the `window.onload = function showPopUp(el) {...}` part to wait 3 seconds from when the script loaded.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
    var dlg = document.getElementById("dialog")
    cvr.style.display = "block"
    dlg.style.display = "block"
    if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
        cvr.style.width = "1024"
        cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
    }
}, 3000);
```

---

Or reverse the `setTimeout` and `window.onload` to wait 3 seconds after all the resources finished loading.

```
window.onload = function showPopUp(el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
       // ...
    }, 3000);
};
```